# Counting word frequency by python list

Tags: python

Today i was trying to write a code to return the number of times a word is repeated in a text (the text that a txt file contains). at first , before i use a dictionary i wanted to test if the list is working and the words are appended into it so i wrote this code :

```
def word_frequency(file) :
    
    """Returns the frequency of all the words in a txt file"""
    
    with open(file) as f :
        
        arg = f.readlines()
        
        l = []
        
        for line in arg :
            l = line.split(' ')
            
            return l
```

After i gave it the file address and i pressed f5 this happened :

```
In[18]: word_frequency("C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Workspace/New folder/tesst.txt")

Out[18]: ['Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello\n']
```

- At first you may think that there is no problem with this output but the text in the txt file is :

[image: text file content]

As you can see , it only appends the words of the first line to the list but i want all the words that are in the txt file to be appended to the list.

Does anyone know what i have to do? what is the problem here ?

Comment: The indentation of the return statement is wrong, it will be called for every line thus ending the function after the first line already. You need to unindent it by one level

Comment: Your function returns after the first iteration of the for loop

Comment: align your `return l` with `with` code line. And initialize `l=[]` before `with` and append new line to it.

Comment: Reindenting the `return` statement won't be enough, it will make it return the last line instead

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question. Use correct upper case letters (e.g. at the beginning of a sentence).

Answer (score 0):

You should save the words in the main list before returning the list.

```py
def word_frequency(file): 

    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        words = []
        for line in lines:
            line_words = line.split()
            words += line_words

        return words
```

In your code, you are saving and returning only the first line, `return` terminates the execution of the function and returns a value. Which in your case is just the first line of the file.

Answer (score -1):

One answer is from [https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/count-the-frequency-of-elements-in-a-list#:~:text=Count%20frequency%20of%20elements%20in%20a%20list%20using,the%20frequency%20of%20the%20element%20in%20the%20list](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/count-the-frequency-of-elements-in-a-list#:%7E:text=Count%20frequency%20of%20elements%20in%20a%20list%20using,the%20frequency%20of%20the%20element%20in%20the%20list).

```
import collections

with open(file) as f:
       
    lines = f.readlines()
        
    words = []
        
    for line in lines:
        word = line.split(' ')
        words.append(word)

frequencyDict = collections.Counter(words)
print("Input list is:", words)
print("Frequency of elements is:")
print(frequencyDict)
```

Comment: As a bonus, if you just want to split on whitespace, you can simply do `.split()`

For example

`'a f fff 123     12345      kljh'.split()`
returns
`['a', 'f', 'fff', '123', '12345', 'kljh']`

Comment: Can someone explain why this got downvoted?

Comment: Probably, because it doesn't answer the question. The OP asks why their code doesn't work, not how to use someone else's code.